# Streaming live image with HLS

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I have a stream of images that come from a live video (RTP), the images pass through a pipeline of transformations, and I would like to stream the video again using HLS to the enduser, How can I take the buffer of images and stream it live using HLS ?

---

The current solution that I m using is returning the frames using http which is too slow and not scalable.

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return Response(gen(),
                  mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

def gen():
    while True:
        time.sleep(.04)
        data = get()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + data.tobytes() + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

Comment: Hello @Brad, HLS is widely use, and I think it will be very scalable comparing to the solution above, I never heard of HTTP progressive stream, can you please guide me to some resource if it's possible, thanks.

Comment: Why not just use FFmpeg to read in your RTP stream and output whatever format you want?